# Flexbox css, position at center of the page

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to position the green box in the center of the page but totally unsuccessfully.

I set the body as flex..this should allow me to align the inside container to the center but it doesn't work. Why?

[image: page]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="signup.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/5ab317586b.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body class="body">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="box-1">
            <h2>Box1</h2>
            <p>This is the box 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-2">
            <h2>Box2</h2>
            <p>This is the box 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="box-3">
            <h2>Box3</h2>
            <p>This is the box 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.body{
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;

}

.container div {
    border: solid red;
    padding: 0;
}

.container{
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;

}
```

I want the green box in the middle, what I'm doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: `body { height: 100% }` is an useless decleration. 100% means 100% of the parents height. The parents height is calculated to fit-content (undefined). 100% of undefined is still undefined. You need to give the body a defined value such as `100vh`. Beyond that, there is barely a reason to give the body a class instead of addressing it directly. Also this is commonly asked question. If you would have used the search function you would have gotten hundreds of result here on SO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to assign height in `vh` and add `justify-content: center;` to your body css. the following body css will align it to center

```
.body{
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: ohh thanks.. that 100vh work. but why need the vh? sorry I'm totally new in html

Comment: as @tacoshy mentioned 

100% means 100% of the parents height. The parents height is calculated to fit-content (undefined). 100% of undefined is still undefined. You need to give the body a defined value such as 100vh. 100vh mean 100 view height.

Answer (score 0):

As Anis has mentioned the body need to be assigned a height so there will be space for the centering to work.

This version uses min-height so the page will be able to scale as more content being added later.

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```